# What is the solution to the system $\frac{df_n}{dt} = kf_{n-1}-(k+l)f_n+lf_{n+1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to solve the system

$$
\begin{matrix}
& \frac{df_1}{dt} = kf_1+lf_2 \\
& \vdots \\
& \frac{df_n}{dt} = kf_{n-1}-(k+l)f_n+lf_{n+1} \\
& \vdots \\
& \frac{df_N}{dt} = kf_{N-1}-lf_N
\end{matrix}
\tag{1}$$

with $f_1 (0) = f_0$ and $\forall n \neq 1 \ [f_n(0)=0]$, where $k$, $l$ and $f_0$ are real positive constants.

The system may also be represented diagrammatically as $\fbox{1}\leftrightarrow
\fbox{2}\leftrightarrow
\fbox{3}\leftrightarrow
\cdots\leftrightarrow
\fbox{N}$ if this is desired.

What is the solution to that system?

I would like to study the cases where $N$ is finite and arbitrarily large.

The standard general method (substitute exponentials, solve the resulting linear system) when followed directly becomes untractable for large N; I believe that a method that takes advantage of particular features of the problem besides linearity will be fruitful. There are two methods that I have considered, but I have been unable to carry out the calculation in either of them to completion.

First, a direct method, using Laplace transforms; a strategy that renders the solution of the case $l=0$ particularly easy. Setting $t\rightarrow lt$ and defining $r = \tfrac{k}{l}$ eliminates one parameter, so that for some $n \neq 1,N$

$$
\frac{df_n}{dt} = rf_{n-1}-(r+1)f_n+f_{n+1}
$$

Taking the laplace transform ($f(t) \mapsto \tilde{f}(s)$) and rewriting the system in matrix form leads to the linear system

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 s+r   &   -1   &   0    &    0    &    0    &        & \cdots & \cdots &  0  \\
 -r    &  s+r+1 &  -1    &    0    &    0    &        & \cdots & \cdots &  0  \\
  0    &   -r   & s+r+1  &   -1    &    0    &        & \cdots & \cdots &  0  \\
  0    &    0   &  -r    &  s+r+1  &   -1    &        & \cdots & \cdots &  0  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  &         & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &\vdots\\
   0   &    0   &    0   &    0    & \cdots  & 0      &   -r   & s+r+1  &  -1 \\
   0   &    0   &    0   &    0    & \cdots  & 0      &    0   &  -r    & s+1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\mathbf{f}_s
=
f_0
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\vdots\\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\Leftrightarrow \mathcal{T}_{N,s} \mathbf{f}_s = 
f_0 
\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\\ \vdots \end{pmatrix}
$$

I am not sure how to proceed with solving this system, however I do believe that a recursive relation can be found without too much effort. I also suspect that the fact that $\mathcal{T}$ is a tridiagonal 'perturbed' Toeplitz matrix should help in the calculation.
However, since this solution leads to rational functions with an N-th degree polynomial in the denominator, for which the inverse Laplace transform must be calculated and in general factorising a polynomial of arbitrary degree cannot be done analytically, I abandon the calculation at this stage (I have worked out solutions for N=3 but even then the calculations are very long and tedious when done directly). There may be some shortcut to estimating the solution using this method - but I fail to see it.

The second method that I have tried (which in reality it is more of an outline than a complete calculation) is to notice that the original system can be seen as a sum of all possible (and terminating) 'histories', such as $\fbox{1} \fbox{2} \fbox{3} \fbox{2} \fbox{3} \fbox{4} \cdots$ and $\fbox{1} \fbox{2} \fbox{3} \fbox{4} \fbox{5} \fbox{4} \fbox{3} \fbox{2} \cdots$. The solution for individual 'histories' (for the intermediate states) will be of the form

$$
\sum_{m} { \left[ a_m \frac{(-kt)^m}{m!} e^{-kt} + b_m \frac{(-lt)^m}{m!} e^{-lt} \right] }
\tag{2}
$$

implying that the final solution of (1) must have a representation of the form $$\sum_{Histories} {\sum_{m} { \left[ a_m \frac{(-kt)^m}{m!} e^{-kt} + b_m \frac{(-lt)^m}{m!} e^{-lt} \right] }}$$ so that perhaps a solution like (2) can be used as an ansatz for the original equation. But I am not certain if this process is along the right path either.

I have also thought of follwoing the usual method for linear systems of ODEs, i.e. calculating the spectrum of $\mathcal{T}_{r,1}$

$$
\mathcal{T}_{r,1} =
\begin{pmatrix}
  -r   &    1    &    0   &    0    & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
   r   &   -r-1  &    1   &    0    & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
   0   &    r    &  -r-1  &    1    & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots &        &        &        \\
       &         &        &         &        &    r   &  -r-1  &   -1   \\
       &         &        &         & \cdots &    0   &    r   &   -1   \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

which contains $-r-1$ alsong the diagonal (apart of positions {1,1} and {N,N}, which are $-r$ and $-1$ respecively) $r$ in the subdiagonal and $-1$ in the superdiagonal. I am not certain how to calculate this either for arbitrary N.

Help will be greatly appreciated!