# Is it possible to calculate the roots of the difference between successive terms of this polynomial series $\rm{P}_n (x)=x\rm{P}_{n-1}-r\rm{P}_{n-2}$

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations, roots, chebyshev-polynomials

Consider the polynomial series defined by the following recursion formula:

$$
\begin{align}
&\mathrm{P}_0 = 1 \\
&\mathrm{P}_1 = x-r \\
&\mathrm{P}_n = x\mathrm{P}_{n-1} - r\mathrm{P}_{n-2} \\
\end{align}
\tag{1}
$$

where $r \in \Bbb{R}_+$

**What are the roots of $\mathrm{Q}_n(x)$, defined as**

$$
\mathrm{Q}_n = \mathrm{P}_{n+1} - \mathrm{P}_{n}
\tag{2}
$$

**Can a formula for these zeros be found?** The recursion relation for $\mathrm{P}_n$ is similar to the definitions of Chebyshev polynomials and Fibonacci polynomials, so I suspect that a way to calculate their roots must exist as well - but I do not know what it is. Interestigly the numerical coefficients (without the various powers of the parameter $r$) are listed in [OEIS sequence A108299](https://oeis.org/A108299).

The first few $\mathrm{Q}_n$ are

$$
\begin{align}
& \mathrm{Q}_1 = \mathrm{P}_1 - \mathrm{P}_0 = x   -(r+1) \\
& \mathrm{Q}_2 = \mathrm{P}_2 - \mathrm{P}_1 = x^2 -(r+1)x   \\
& \mathrm{Q}_3 = \mathrm{P}_3 - \mathrm{P}_2 = x^3 -(r+1)x^2 - rx   + r(r+1) \\
& \mathrm{Q}_4 = \mathrm{P}_4 - \mathrm{P}_3 = x^4 -(r+1)x^3 -2rx^2 +2r(r+1)x \\
& \mathrm{Q}_5 = \mathrm{P}_5 - \mathrm{P}_4 = x^5 -(r+1)x^4 -3rx^3 +3r(r+1)x^2 +  r^2 x   -  r^2(r+1) \\
& \mathrm{Q}_6 = \mathrm{P}_6 - \mathrm{P}_5 = x^6 -(r+1)x^5 -4rx^4 +4r(r+1)x^3 + 3r^2 x^2 - 3r^2(r+1)x \\
& \mathrm{Q}_7 = \mathrm{P}_7 - \mathrm{P}_6 = x^7 -(r+1)x^6 -5rx^5 +5r(r+1)x^4 + 6r^2 x^3 - 6r^2(r+1)x^2 - r^3 x   +  r^3(r+1) \\ 
& \mathrm{Q}_8 = \mathrm{P}_8 - \mathrm{P}_7 = x^8 -(r+1)x^7 -6rx^6 +6r(r+1)x^5 +10r^2 x^4 -10r^2(r+1)x^3 -4r^3 x^2 + 4r^3(r+1)x  \\
\end{align}
$$

The magnitude of the numerical coefficients are listed in [OEIS A011973](https://oeis.org/A011973) (the difference being that here they are doubled).

I also propose these conjectures, only one of which (#2) I have been able to prove:

1. $r+1$ is a root of all $\mathrm{Q_n}$
2. $0$ is a root for all $\mathrm{Q_n}$ of even order ($n$ even)
3. if $\mathcal{R}$ is a root and $\mathcal{R} \neq r+1$ then $-\mathcal{R}$ is also a root.
4. all roots of $\mathrm{Q}_n$ have multiplicity $1$ (are single roots).

This problem is related to solving the linear system I describe [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878533/what-is-the-solution-to-the-system-fracdf-ndt-kf-n-1-klf-nlf-n1).

I do not know how to tackle this problem generally, help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which one did you manage to prove?

Comment: @QuangHoang Conjecture (2). It can be seen from the definition of $\rm{P}_n$ that the power of the constant term $r$ changes for every odd $n$, so that it will vanish when the difference of two successive terms is taken when the highest -order term is of an even power.

Comment: Well, then the first fact is easy. Just note that $Q_n$ also satisfy $Q_n=xQ_{n-1}-rQ_{n-2}$ and that $r+1$ is a root of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$.

Comment: @QuangHoang Indeed! :D
I'm trying to think of some substitution that might give the  series in a form where the zeros can be read from with relative ease, as can be done for several recursively defined polynomial series... but I haven't found one yet

Comment: Conjecture 3 can be proved the same way; define $Q_n(x) = (x-r-1)R_n(x)$ and note that the $R_n$ satisfy the same recurrence $R_n = xR_{n-1} - R_{n-2}$.  One can then prove by induction that if $n$ is even then $R_n(x)$ is odd and if $n$ is odd then $R_n(x)$ is even.

Comment: Let $R_n(x)=Q_n(x)/(x-r-1)$. I believe all of the statements can be answered by looking at $R_n(x)$ as orthogonal polynomials with respect to a certain inner product on the set of polynomials.

Comment: @AntonioVargas How interesting! Btw I assume that the recurrence relation for $R_n$ is the same, i.e. $R_n = xR_{n-1} - rR_{n-1}$ (i.e. that the missing $r$ is a typo). Do you think that there is a way to determine the roots of $R_n$ ?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, sorry.  It turns out your polynomials are just scaled and shifted Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind; see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define

$$
U_n(x) = r^{-n/2} (2\sqrt{r} x-r-1)^{-1} Q_{n+1}(2 \sqrt{r} x).
$$

We see that $U_0(x) = 1$, $U_1(x) = 2x$, and

$$
U_n(x) = 2x U_{n-1}(x) - U_{n-2}(x),
$$

so these $U_n$ are in fact [Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Definition).  Thus

$$
Q_n(x) = r^{n/2}(x-r-1) U_n(x/2\sqrt{r}).
$$

Comment: Cool! I suspected that they would have something to do with Chebyshev polynomials! Thanks!!

Comment: I've also been wondering - are there some techniques that can be used for calculating the roots of recursively defined polynomial series? I think I want to try and calculate the roots of $P_n$ as well.

Comment: In general there are not closed-form formulas for the roots of recursively defined polynomials.  Usually one must resort to numerical methods to calculate them to some desired precision.  People also study them asymptotically to obtain approximate formulas for their location or distribution, and there is a lot of literature on that subject.